# Icons in widget sometimes broken / black

Tags: android, android-widget, imageview

I implemented a widget, which is working quite well in general. However, here and there I get reports from users that some of the images in the Widget are broken (black, to be exactly). I included a screenshot from a [Motorola Razr i (XT890)](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_razr_i_xt890-4998.php) device, which seems to have exactly the explained problem. All icons reside in the drawable-hdpi resource folder in a PNG format.

What could be a possible explanation for such behavior?

Here is a code snippet how I assign the images to the widget:

```
public static void updateWidgetData(RemoteViews view, String id, Integer idWidget, String background, String showTitle, String titleAlpha, Context context) {
    ...
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, AndroidUtil.getLowMemoryBitmapOptions());
    view.setImageViewBitmap(idWeatherIcon, bitmap));
    ...
}

public static BitmapFactory.Options getLowMemoryBitmapOptions() {   
    /** BITMAP FACTORY OPTIONS **/
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOpts = new BitmapFactory.Options();     
    bitmapOpts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;       
    bitmapOpts.inPurgeable = true;
    bitmapOpts.inInputShareable  = true;
    /** END BITMAP FACTORY OPTIONS **/
    return bitmapOpts;
}
```

[image: One icon does not load correctly]

*The black icons appear at random positions, so the example is just one possibility where the error happens...*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cant comment, but want to suggest to check the following:

1. what options for BitmapFactory are returned by `AndroidUtil.getLowMemoryBitmapOptions()` when on this Motorola and when on a device where it shows as it should.
2. check all images, one or more might be different somehow (maybe alpha channel/transparency?)
3. could be related to one of the above and the device/GPU/OS version (because of Android fragmentation, you never know what you can discover).

Comment: **1)** I updated my Question with the code for the getLowMemoryBitmapOptions(). The options are on every device the same. **2)** Checked the images, all are from the same source, definitely all the same **3)** My opinion is that it is highly unlikely that the device/GPU/OS have to do with it. I would rather assume a custom Home Screen implementation from Motorola - [Motoblur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motoblur)

Comment: The home screen shouldn't affect the widget partially (all the images should be black maybe). You could install a different Launcher, like the Go Launcher, and give it a try. For testing purpose, comment out `bitmapOpts.inPurgeable = true;
    bitmapOpts.inInputShareable  = true;` and change to ARGB_8888.